# Invalid Cast Exception radbutton telerik (oncheckedchanged)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, telerik

I'm using a telerik Radbutton to act like a checkbox.
However, when I click on the checkbox I receive a `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Webapplicatie.dll`

See code below for asp.net code:

```
   <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Hele dag" ToggleType="CheckBox" ButtonType="ToggleButton"  OnCheckedChanged="RadButton1_CheckedChanged">
                        </telerik:RadButton>
```

and:

```
protected void RadButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (RadButton1.Checked)
                {
                    lbStarttijd.Visible = false;
                    lbEindtijd.Visible = false;

                    rtp_Eindtijd.Visible = false;
                    rtp_Starttijd.Visible = false;
                    //rtp_Eindtijd.Enabled = false;
                    //rtp_Starttijd.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lbStarttijd.Visible = true;
                    lbEindtijd.Visible = true;
                    //lbEindtijd.Enabled = true;
                    //lbStarttijd.Enabled = true;
                    rtp_Eindtijd.Visible = true;
                    rtp_Starttijd.Visible = true;
                    //rtp_Eindtijd.Enabled = true;
                    //rtp_Starttijd.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

However, the weirdest thing is, it does not end up in my Catch.
I don't see why this is causing a invalid cast exception. Help appreciated :)

**Side Note:** This only happens when I 'bash' the checkbox by spam-clicking it.

Comment: Not 100% on this one so I won't make it answer just yet, but I'm assuming that your checkbox (radiobutton) is causing a postback and your error is somewhere else in your code, and not in the code you posted. If possible post up any code that fires on page load.

Comment: @KreepN adding AutoPostBack="false" does not solve the issue. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: "If you want to pinpoint where the exceptions are occurring, you can select the Debug->Exceptions menu item, and in the dialog that appears, check the first checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This will make the debugger break as soon as an exception occurs instead of only breaking on unhandled exceptions." - Per another thread. Give that a go and see if you can get the exception.

Comment: @KreepN If you can post that reply as answer, I will be more than glad to mark is as the answer solving the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: But was the actual cause for the exception?

Comment: My error-webservice is using some arguments, and one of them was "Request.Form" without using a form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to find the root cause of the exception:

"If you want to pinpoint where the exceptions are occurring, you can select the Debug->Exceptions menu item, and in the dialog that appears, check the first checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

This will make the debugger break as soon as an exception occurs instead of only breaking on unhandled exceptions." - Per another thread.

Give that a go and see if you can get the exception.